# Where can i find the logic for storing last status of volume in android framework?

Tags: android

I have a database where i store the volume values. When reinstalled or rebooted or software upgrade i want my stored volume to be applied rather than androids.

Please guide me .

Comment: Here is the guide http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please include any code of your project and what you've tried so far. This will help get you a more relevant answer to the community. Please see the guide @Areca provided above for more details on asking questions. Thank you!

Comment: Oh seriously guys??? I just needed some architectural guidance.